# how to upload video to youtube through access_token

Tags: android, youtube-api

have gain access token by AccounPicker and GoogleAuthUtil.getToken. but can not find a way use token upload video to youtube

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried so far? Have you had a chance to take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#examples)?

Comment: @pointNclick  Thanks your response.
I use google-sigin not google-client-api but only gain the access token.
use Youtube-Data-api-v3, need the client id and client secrity.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the access token, you're almost there. Client ID and Client Secret can be created from [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). One of many, but [here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jg__b_WM5gg) a video that'll show you how to do that. Although the Dev Console UI has now changed from what's shown in the video, but the basics remain the same. Hence, you should be able to figure it out by playing around a little bit. I will also recommend making yourself familiar with [this](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/) help page for further info.